# How to escape (\t \n \r) when use "load data into outfile" in mysql?

Tags: mysql

How to escape (\t \n \r) when use "load data into outfile" in mysql?

I have tried to do this:

```
select * from user INTO OUTFILE FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

but it seems not work

I need a example.

### thx

If I insert a value into field `var` with content "\r\n":

```
+----+------+------+
| id | var  | var2 |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | 
   | test |
+----+------+------+
```

then, run

```
SELECT * FROM `test` into OUTFILE '/tmp/out.log' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

The 'out.log':

```
1       \
        test
```

ASCII:
`31 09 5c 0d 0a 09 74 65 73 74 0d 0a`

But I want to escape `0d 0a`

Comment: What means `but it seems not work`

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from user INTO OUTFILE 'path' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```